# Dynamically display PDF in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, struts

In the code, when the user clicks on a link, it will display a PDF on the same page at the top. For every object, a different PDF will be displayed. The problem is that the PDF are not displaying at all. The PDFs are stored in a bytes format taken from a BLOB object. I am using Struts1. I know that the data attribute is supposed to be a link so how do I display the PDF when I don't have a link but the PDF itself? Also how do I change the PDF whenever a link is clicked? This is what I have tried:

```
<logic:notEmpty name="catalogList">
    <table class="data">
        <c:forEach items="${catalogList}" var="catalog">
            <div id="pdf" style="display: none;">
                <object data="${catalog.bytes}" type="application/pdf" width="500"
                    height="300">
                </object>
            </div>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th><html:checkbox property="identityArray"
                            value="${catalog.id}"></html:checkbox></th>
                    <th>I accept the <a href="#" id="tag"> Terms and
                            Conditions</a> for Catalog <c:out value="${catalog.description}" /></th>
                </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td><html:button styleClass="submit"
                        onclick="forwardAction(this.form);" property="">
                        <bean:message key="button.add" />
                    </html:button></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</logic:notEmpty>
```

Comment: Does the generated HTML look as expected?

Comment: The checkboxes are coming correctly but the object part is just showing a gray block with a loading bar and Initializing written in it.

Comment: Look at the generated HTML source.  You need to understand what is begin generated _now_ as well as what you _want_ in order to figure out what to change.